# Can I add transition animation between two reactive values when building Shiny app with rCharts?

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

I have a slider in the Shiny app for a reactive value, and I am using rCharts for the plotting. Can I add some transition animation to the chart when I drag the slider, so that the chart will not change suddenly? As I know [nvd3](http://nvd3.org/) supports transitions so I expect rCharts, at least with nvd3, would support that.

**Update**: an example

`ui.r`:

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  withMathJax(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel=sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("lambda", "\\(\\lambda=\\)", 
                  min=0, max=1, value=0.5, step=0.05)),
    mainPanel=mainPanel(
      showOutput("chart", "nvd3")
    )
  )
))
```

`server.r`:

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)

n <- 10
d <- 2
data_1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(n * d), nrow=n, ncol=d))
data_2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(n * d), nrow=n, ncol=d))

shinyServer(function(input, output){
  output$chart <- renderChart({
    data <- data_1 * input$lambda + data_2 * (1 - input$lambda)
    p <- nPlot(x="V1", y="V2", data=data, type="scatterChart")
    p$set(dom="chart")
    return(p)
  })
})
```

When changing the value of lambda, the chart changes accordingly. But how to add transition animations between the two charts of two lambdas? Thank you.

Comment: a replicable example would be very helpful.  Can you provides some code, so that we might better understand chart type and data?

Comment: @timelyportfolio an example is added.

Comment: @ziyuang – did you manage to find a way to implement some custom transitions? I have the same problem…